# Corona Sdk - Is there a way to call and group:insert() an object from another lua file?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

As stated in the title I would like to not only call an object from an external Lua file, but I would also like to `group:insert()` this object into my Menu page with the properties given to it in the external lua file.  Is this possible and/or efficient? I would just really like to make sure data isn't repeated through out my project.

*EDIT*

Here's my code so far:
The group:insert() function is throwing me an error stating it was expecting a table and that I might have been trying to call a function in which case i should use ":" instead of "."

This is menu.lua:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local widget = require "widget"
local m = require ("myData")
local menuFunction = require("menuFunction")
local menuSwipe

-- =======================
-- menuSwipe()
-- =======================
menuSwipe = function(self, event)
    local phase = event.phase
    local touchID = event.id


    if(phase == "began") then
    elseif(phase == "moved") then
    elseif(phase == "ended" or phase == "cancelled") then
        if(m.menuActivator > 0) then
            menuDown(m.invisiBar, event)
        else
            --m.layerInfo = layers
            transition.to( menuFunction.menuBar, { x = menuFunction.menuBar.x, y = 0, time = 200 } ) 
            --transition.to( layers, { x = menuFunction.menuBar.x, y = h, time = 100 } )
            m.invisiBar = display.newRect( 0,0,w,25,6)
            m.invisiBar.alpha = 0
            m.menuActivator = 1
        end
    end
end

-- ++++++++++++++++++++++
-- menuDown()
-- ++++++++++++++++++++++
function menuDown(self, event)
    local phase = event.phase
    local touchID = event.id

    if(phase == "began") then
    elseif(phase == "moved") then
    elseif(phase == "ended" or phase == "cancelled") then
        if(m.menuActivator == 1) then
            transition.to( menuFunction.menuBar, { x = m.menuInfo.x, y = h*.964, time = 200 } )
            --transition.to( group, { x = 0, y = 0, time = 10 } ) 
            m.menuActivator = 0
        end
    end
end

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view


    group:insert( menuFunction.menuBar ) -- *** ERROR occurs here


end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view 
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

This is menuFunction.lua:

```
local m = require("myData")
local menu = require ("menu")

local w = display.contentWidth
local h = display.contentHeight

local menuFunction = {}
    --menuBar
    menuFunction.menuBar = display.newImage( "images/menuBar1.png")
    menuFunction.menuBar.x = w*(1/2)
    menuFunction.menuBar.y = h*1.465
    menuFunction.menuBar.height = h
    menuFunction.menuBar:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
    menuFunction.menuBar.touch = menu.menuSwipe
    menuFunction.menuBar:addEventListener("touch", menuFunction.menuBar)

return menuFunction
```

This is the exact error message:

```
ERROR: table expected. If this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':'
message**
```

Comment: Did u searched it on the internet?

Comment: I did indeed with zero helpful results.. I found out how to save data in another lua file and also how to call functions from another lua file however trying both of these yielded nothing but errors.  So I was hoping someone could show me a good way to insert an object and its properties from another lua file.

Comment: then probably u should hve to put your code here

Comment: Please flag the line where error occurs and the exact (copy) error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this happen every time this code is called, or does it by any chance work the first time and then crashes? In your case, code could work the first time you enter the scene, but the second time you do, it may crash [if you remove scenes in between].

When you do a 'require' of a file, its contents are executed and returned value is saved in the global packages table. When you require the same file again, the returned value is taken from the global packages table instead, the code is not executed again.

So if you by any chance require this file in one spot of your app, and then call :removeSelf() and nil the reference of the menuBar, the display object will be removed and its reference will cease to exist, and calling the require again, will not recreate the object. Fully removing a scene will also remove the display objects.

So what you wanted to achieve is very sensible [contrary to what @Schollii says], but your "module" should allow creation of multiple objects if you want to get rid of them during runtime.

I'm not going to correct your code, just a simple example of how you can achieve this:

```
-- menu.lua

local menuCreator = {}
menuCreator.newMenu = function(params)
    local menu = display.newGroup()
    -- create your menu here
    return menu
end
return menuCreator
```

Now anytime you do:

```
local menuCreator = require("menu.lua")
```

you will be able to call:

```
local menu = menuCreator.newMenu(someParams)
```

and get yourself a nice new menu wherever you need.
If it's not shown all the time on screen, it may be better to create a new one whenever you need it, and then remove it from the memory.

Comment: Thank you Krystian for your very well thought out response! This is actually what I ended up doing to make it work.  Sorry I probably should have posted that I had figured it out on here a while ago, but hopefully this will help others in the future.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, just +1 and accept the answer if you really ended up doing this. It might help others :)

Comment: unfortunately I am not allowed to +1 you because I have less than 15 rep :( sorry, but I'll be sure to come back when I do :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this, and none of them seem related to your error but fixing them will either also fix the error or make the cause of the error more obvious. Please fix following and update:

- Although Lua allows it, don't use circular includes, where A includes B which includes A. Instead have menu require menuFunction and then call a creation function in menuFuntion:

  ```
  -- menuFunction.lua
  local m = require("myData")
  -- require("menu") -- BAD! :)

  local w = display.contentWidth
  local h = display.contentHeight

  local menuBar = display.newImage( "images/menuBar1.png")
  menuBar.x = w*(1/2)
  menuBar.y = h*1.465
  menuBar.height = h
  menuBar:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
  local menuFunction = { menuBar = menuBar }

  function createMenuBar(menuSwipe)
      menuFunction.menuBar.touch = menuSwipe
      menuFunction.menuBar:addEventListener("touch", menuFunction.menuBar)
      return menuFunction
  end

  -- menu.lua
  function createScene(event)
      local mf = require('menuFunction')
      mfFunction = mf.createMenuBar(menuSwipe)
      group:insert(menuFunction.menuBar)
  end
  ```
- Secondly out of the four calls to group:insert() the first 3 refer to objects that are not shown in the code and don't see relevant to problem, they should be removed or if you think relevant, comment why their code now shown, or show their code.